# Save array after lodash remove

Tags: node.js, lodash

So I have this code:

```
_.remove(user.items, userItem => userItem.id === sellingItem.id);

user.save();
```

What it currently does is that it removes one item from the array but the problem is when I save the user the array still has the same removed item in it. When I do `splice` and save the user the item is removed from the database too. Why this doesn't work with `remove`?

**EDIT**

```
_.remove(user.items, userItem => userItem.id === sellingItem.id);
const newArray = user.items; // array without the item
user.items = newArray;
user.save();
```

In database is still old array.

Comment: `remove` will return a new array with the modification you specified. All the Lodash methods work like that - they will take an array and some callback and return an array that corresponds to applying the callback over the original.

Comment: Yeah it returns the new array without the item and even though I save the user, the array still has all items as before in database.

Comment: You never *change* the original array, though. `user.items` remains exactly the same as before calling `_.remove`.

Comment: `// array without the item` this is NOT the array without the item. In fact, it's nothing but a reference to the exact same array - `newArray` is *literally* the same array as before, not even a copy of it with the same contents. `_.remove` does not *modify* the array it works on, it will construct an entirely new array and *return it* as the result of the invocation. So, if you want to use that, you need to capture the return result `const newArray = _.remove(/* ... */)`

Comment: Okay `newArray = _.remove(/* ... */)` is the problem too cause it returns REMOVED ITEM not all array. So if I set `newArray` to `user.items` theres only one item left. My method below still works

Answer (score -1):

This is what worked for me.

```
            _.remove(user.items, userItem => userItem.id === sellingItem.id);
            const newArray = user.items;

            user.items = [];
            user.items = newArray;

            user.save();
```